# Are knots determined by their complements within a homotopy class?

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, knot-theory

Suppose $M$ is a closed 3-manifold and $K_1,K_2$ are two homotopic knots in $M$.  That is, they are two embeddings $f_1,f_2\colon S^1 \to M$ such that there exists a homotopy $h\colon S^1 \times [0,1] \to M$ with $h(x,0) = f_1(x)$ and $h(x,1) = f_2(x)$.  Suppose also that there is an orientation preserving homeomorphism $M - K_1 \to M - K_2$.  Must $K_1$ and $K_2$ be isotopic in $M$?

A positive result seems like it would have fairly large implications, not to mention being necessarily more difficult than Gordon and Luecke's result (and is therefore unreasonable to expect here) so I am mainly wondering if there are any known or simple counterexamples.

Answer (score 7):

The answer is *no*.

It stems from the fact that links are not determined by their complements.  If you take the Borromean rings (for example), and think of one component as being a knot in the exterior of the other two components, i.e. a knot in the connect sum of two copies of $S^1 \times D^2$, then this knot is homotopic to another knot, which when put together with the other two components of the Borromean rings, is *not* isotopic to the Borromean rings, but the complement is diffeomorphic, preserving orientation.

You get these homotopic but not isotopic knots by doing a Dehn twist along a spanning disc for one of the other two components -- or you could do it on both simultaneously.

I suppose the Whitehead link would also work.

Perhaps instead of describing the second link via the Dehn twist it would be more appropriate to describe the homotopy as a "finger move" pushing one crossing over the other.

Comment: Thanks for the observation.   The Whitehead link (among others) does seem to work for the case where $M$ has boundary.  However, I'm mainly interested in when $M$ is closed, preventing that kind of twisting operation.

Comment: I think you can make these examples work as well -- just embed these 3-manifolds in a closed 3-manifold in a way that doesn't allow the knots to become isotopic.  The Whitehead example works fine if you double the manifold (the complement of one component of the link).  I suspect the Borromean rings one will work similarly.  Alternatively do a Dehn filling of slope 0 on the manifolds.

Comment: I believe that doing a Dehn filling of slope 0, at the very least, does not work.  You can slide the knot across the filled meridian disk to get the same effect as a twist would have, and therefore you have an isotopy.  I am not sure how doubling works in this case since you need to end up with a closed manifold and it is not clear to me that the complements will still be homeomorphic.

Comment: I am very confused on how doubling works here, because 1) we change the complements, and 2) I don't see what stops the knots from moving through the double to become isotopic. Am I correct in the setup that we first take $X:=S^3-\text{nbhd}(J)$ where $J$ is one component of the Whitehead link $J\cup K$ and then consider $K$ (along with some homotopic knot $K'$) inside $M=D(X)$? If so, then granted $J\cup K$ is not isotopic to $J\cup K′$ in $S^3$, I don't see how to use this to prove that $K$ is not isotopic to $K′$ in $M$. That is, why $K\cong K'$ in $M\;\Rightarrow\;K\cong K'$ in $X$?